# How to print the first response

Tags: python-3.x, openai-api

All,

I have the below code :

```
messages = [
    {
        "role" : "system",
        "content" : "You are a movie expert"
    },
    {
        "role": "user",
        "content": "Can you summarize the movie Spy Game"
    },
    {
        "role": "user",
        "content": "In which all locations was the movie shot"
    }
]
```

Currently the below code only prints the second User response and not the first one.

```
response = client.chat.completions.create(
    model = model,
    messages = messages
)

print(response.choices[0].message.content)
```

**How do I print the first user response as well?**

Comment: You have to provide some more context for your question. What are you trying to do? What framework are you using? Which programming language is the code for?